# Need to login using credentials from postgres database table from ftp client

Tags: postgresql, ftp, rds, proftpd

Installed proftp to enable ftpserver on ec2 instance and I need to login using credentials from postgres database table from ftp client.

Did configuration as suggested in following link:
https://galaxyproject.org/admin/config/upload-via-ftp/

If anyone can help me where I am missing anything??

Getting following error

```
 2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal: RELINQUISH PRIVS at main.c:1268
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal: no matching vhost found for 127.0.0.1#21, using 'ProFTPD Default Installation' listening on wildcard address
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): ROOT PRIVS at main.c:1073
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): SETUP PRIVS at main.c:1078
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): session requested from client in unknown class
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): performing module session initializations
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): mod_sql/4.3: defaulting to 'postgres' backend
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): mod_delay/0.7: no DelayOnEvent rules configured with "DelayTable none" in effect, disabling module
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): ROOT PRIVS at mod_auth.c:215
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): opening scoreboard '/opt/apps/proftpd1.3.6/var/proftpd.scoreboard'
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_auth.c:217
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): connected - local  : 127.0.0.1:21
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): connected - remote : 127.0.0.1:40094
2017-07-18 07:12:36,935 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): FTP session opened.
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_auth
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_auth
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching POST_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching POST_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_log
2017-07-18 07:12:50,533 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD command 'USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_sql_passwd
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): USER galaxyadmin@gmail.com: no such user found from localhost6 [127.0.0.1] to 127.0.0.1:21
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching POST_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_log
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_delay
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD_ERR command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'SYST' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'SYST' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching CMD command 'SYST' to mod_core
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching POST_CMD command 'SYST' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD command 'SYST' to mod_sql
2017-07-18 07:12:56,303 ip-172-31-9-252 proftpd[10487] ip-172-31-9-252.us-west-2.compute.internal (localhost6[127.0.0.1]): dispatching LOG_CMD command 'SYST' to mod_log
```

Comment: I have a ProFTPd installation that works. Now I'm trying to route the authentication through postgres. There is a database that contains a table of webapp users. This will ideally allow webapp users to login to the FTP using their webapp credentials

Comment: If you configure an [`SQLLogFile`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html#SQLLogFile), what does it show?  Hopefully that log will show the query for the user, and why `mod_sql` can't find that user...